# Very large array to CSV and response to a rest api in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I have a very large array with 2000000 records. When I try to send that array to the CSV function in the node, it gives me an Outofmemory exception.

```
res.status(200).csv(BIGARRAY, true);
```

What is the best way to handle this? Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you running your node instance?  `>node file.js`?

Comment: Yes. This is hosted in server.

Comment: Maybe use r-script. Send data to an R script, do your stuff with it then get it back in node under JSON. R would maybe able to handle this quantity if data

Comment: what about streaming data from websockets?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the easiest solution is to throw more memory at it.

You can do this with Node.js like so:

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 fileName.js
```

And keep increasing the limit until it finishes running.

Otherwise, you would have to break your array of 200000 records into smaller arrays and run the `.csv` function on each of them.

Comment: Its not really the memory allocation. Because my array has the data. In CSV, they are trying to convert this array to a single string and convert. That is where it fails.

Comment: You're right that it isn't a memory allocation problem with the array.  The problem is that the cost of the `CSV` operation is causing the node server's memory to throw that error you get: `Outofmemory exception`

Answer (score 0):

How do you get your array? By some kind of stream?
I would suggest you to use streams to avoid memory leak.

```
readableStream.pipe(res);
```

Because express **response** is a writable stream, you can simply pipe and let it handle all memory issues.

Comment: The array is got from running a sql against db.

Comment: What DB are you using? Does it support streaming? if yes, just pipe your readable stream into response of express and you are good to go.